# Fetch a key value pair from raw value key value pair hashmap Java

Tags: java, android, hashmap

Code:

```
 final HashMap<?,?> entryMap = (HashMap<?, ?>) getListView().getItemAtPosition(index);

System.out.println(entryMap.get("raw" ));
```

output :

```
03-04 00:35:33.301: I/System.out(20969): {raw={handle=chai, queued=false, claimable=false, oname=, obasetype=A, opostid=62, userid=11, moderatable=false, parentid=, unflaggable=false, upvotes=2, type=Q, isbyuser=false, deleteable=false, _type=A, flagcount=0, closeable=true, viewable=true, level=0, updated=, created=1393741365, closedbyid=, flagtohide=false, oemail=chan30kcr@yahoo.com, points=330, _time=1393854769, reshowimmed=false, commentable=false, _order_=11, extra=, oavatarblobid=, downvotes=0, followable=false, aselectable=true, lastip=, format=, netvotes=2, retagcatbutton=false, hotness=2.6352e+10, editable=true, _userid=11, ohandle=chai, content=How to register??, avatarwidth=, categoryid=, oavatarheight=, email=chan30kcr@yahoo.com, basetype=Q, answerbutton=true, lastuserid=, avatarheight=, postid=54, commentbutton=false, createip=223.227.82.64, acount=1, sort=-1393854769, olevel=0, hideable=true, selchildid=, oip=223.227.27.110, updatetype=, oavatarwidth=, avatarblobid=, cookieid=, lastviewip=122.167.118.113, oflags=1, title= .., otime=1393854769, reopenable=false, notify=, name=, userfavoriteq=0, userflag=0, closed=false, oflagcount=0, editbutton=true, ohidden=0, tags=, categorybackpath=, flags=1, flagbutton=true, categoryids=, opoints=330, clearflaggable=false, ocookieid=, uservote=1, views=3, hidden=0, reshowable=false, retagcatable=true, categoryname=, ouserid=11, authorlast=true}, closepost=, answers=[Ljava.lang.Object;@410576e0, what_2=answered, extravalue=, who_2={data=<a href="./index.php/user/chai" class="qa-user-link url nickname">chai</a>, title=, level=Registered user, points={data=330, suffix= points, prefix=}, suffix=false, prefix=by }, favorite=0, avatar=, vote_state=voted_up, who={data=<a href="./index.php/user/chai" class="qa-user-link url nickname">chai</a>, title=, level=Registered user, points={data=330, suffix= points, prefix=}, suffix=false, prefix=by }, meta_order=^what^when^where^who, content=How to register??, netvotes_raw=2, username=chan, when_2={data=5 hours, suffix= ago, prefix=}, what=asked, when={data=1 day, suffix= ago, prefix=}, what_2_url=./?show=62#a62, categories=[Ljava.lang.Object;@410579a0, parentquestion=, comments=[Ljava.lang.Object;@410577c8}
```

> link = (String)entryMap.get("what_2_url");

I am able to get the value of what_2_url

but how to get the value inside the {raw={handle=chai, postid=54,

```
  link = (String)entryMap.get("postid");
```

it returns null how to fetch the value using java hashmap

Comment: @fge how to achieve is my question...

Comment: Use a `LinkedHashMap`, iteration order is guaranteed to be insertion order. And put the result of `.entrySet()` into a `List`. Then you'll be able to access it by index.

Comment: @fge can u show me with a example... will be thankful to u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First test what kind of object is returned by using `getClass()` on the value of `link` for `(String)entryMap.get("what_2_url")`and printing it. Then cast `link` to the right class and use a getter or anything defined for that specific class.

A test using `instanceof` before casting is probably a good idea.

---

So in your case:

```
HashMap<?, ?> linkHashMap = (HashMap<?, ?>) link;
System.out.println(linkHashMap.get("postid"));
```

Comment: 03-05 17:51:43.658: I/System.out(13066): class java.util.HashMap

Comment: OK, so cast `link` to `HashMap`, assign it to a new variable `linkHashMap` and then get the right value.

Comment: will try it and let u know the result

Comment: @owlstead... i need the value of postid.. i am able to get the value of key link... postid is inside `{raw={handle=chai, postid=54,`

Comment: `HashMap<?, ?> linkHashMap = (HashMap<?, ?>) entryMap.get("raw" );
System.out.println(linkHashMap.get("postid"));`